# Swype keyboard: how to add a letter to a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, swype

I am using the Swype keyboard on Android. When I hold down a letter on the English keyboard (and others), I can see a list of similar letters with diacritics and other options for Unicode character's to input. I want to add an "h with dot below" to my "h" list. How do I do that?

Thanks..

Comment: It would be killer to be able to shortcut to emoji this way, too.

Comment: True. I hope it gets implemented.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to type h with underdot?